# Get a link from a page and print it

Tags: javascript

this should be pretty easy but I'm having problems with making it work right.

This is for a small warehouse that delivers objects. when someone orders something it appears on a page wich is generated automatically. It is an index.php this is the code that contains the print link :

```
<tr class="">
   <td width="244"  align="left">
     <p style="padding-left:5px; ">
      <strong>1.</strong>
      <strong style=" font-weight:bold; font-size:12">Client Name</strong>
      <br/>     
      <a href="http://site/orders/order.php?id_comanda=15284656"
         target="_blank" onClick="this.blur()">15284656 - auto</a>
      <br />
      <a href="marfa-pregatita.php?nr_aviz=401599413&nr_disp=18129704&act=2"
         target="_blank" onClick="this.blur()">printing link</a><br>
      <span style='color: #FF0000'>times printed : 
      <span style='font-weight:bold';font-size:10pt>1</span> x</span>             
     </p>
     <a name="df_18129704"></a>
   </td>
```

there are multiple codes like this on the page numbered from 1 to how many are there. The "printing link" needs to be opened and printed for everyone of this orders. I am quite new to java coding. How can this be done? the printing link changes only with the "`nr_aviz=401599413&nr_disp=18129704`" just the actual numbers change. Please help! I want this to run as an addon on chrome.

Comment: Have you looked at automated browser driving using something like Selenium? A simple script could automate the process of clicking on each link and printing it. Though the correct way in my opinion to handle this is to add this to the server itself, not trying to do it through the client. Perhaps a PDF download or something like that.

Comment: Don't confuse java and javascript, those are two vastly different languages. Moreover you shouldn't expect too much answers to your question as it is now : it is overly broad (do you have problem getting the page's content? parsing it? displaying it?) and you don't show what you've done yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop a chrome extension, see the [Chrome Extenstions developper documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions) to get started. You'll have to write Javascript code (not Java which is a very different language).

You can select every printing links by using [Javascript CSS selectors API](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#grammar), like so :

```
// selects links (<a ...>) where attribute "href" starts with "marfa-pregatita.php"
var selector = 'a[href^="marfa-pregatita.php"]';
var links = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

// for each link, click on it
for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
  var link = links[i];
  if (link.text == "printing link") {
    link.click();
  }
}
```

You can also run this in Chrome Dev Tools (open it by hitting `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`I`). Go in the Console tab and type your code directly or go in the Sources tab and add your script as a Snippet. It's good place to start in order to create an extension.

Hope this helps.